# Add-ons on Tor Browser - what if it was universal?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity

I have read many times that you shouldn't use additional add-ons on Tor Browser because it makes your browser easier to identify (more susceptible to fingerprinting).

But what if *every Tor Browser Bundle installation* came with uBlock Origin, uMatrix, and Decentraleyes by default instead of just individual people installing add-ons? Wouldn't that also make fingerprinting harder if so many people have the same configuration?

Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, if everyone had these plugins then everyone would look the same.

However, let me share a couple of quotes:

From the [FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherExtensions):

> Some people have suggested we include ad-blocking software or
>   anti-tracking software with Tor Browser. Right now, we do not think
>   that's such a good idea. Tor Browser aims to provide sufficient
>   privacy that additional add-ons to stop ads and trackers are not
>   necessary. Using add-ons like these may cause some sites to break,
>   which we don't want to do. Additionally, maintaining a list of "bad"
>   sites that should be black-listed provides another opportunity to
>   uniquely fingerprint users.

From the [The Design and Implementation of the Tor Browser](https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#philosophy) document:

> **No filters** Site-specific or filter-based addons such as AdBlock Plus, Request Policy, Ghostery, Priv3, and Sharemenot are to be
>   avoided. We believe that these addons do not add any real privacy to a
>   proper implementation of the above privacy requirements, and that
>   development efforts should be focused on general solutions that
>   prevent tracking by all third parties, rather than a list of specific
>   URLs or hosts.
>
> Implementing filter-based blocking directly into the browser, such as
>   done with Firefox' Tracking Protection, does not alleviate the
>   concerns mentioned in the previous paragraph. There is still just a
>   list containing specific URLs and hosts which, in this case, are
>   assembled by Disconnect and adapted by Mozilla.
>
> Trying to resort to filter methods based on machine learning does not
>   solve the problem either: they don't provide a general solution to the
>   tracking problem as they are working probabilistically. Even with a
>   precision rate at 99% and a false positive rate at 0.1% trackers would
>   be missed and sites would be wrongly blocked.
>
> Filter-based solutions in general can also introduce strange breakage
>   and cause usability nightmares. For instance, there is a trend to
>   observe that websites start detecting filer extensions and block
>   access to content on them. Coping with this fallout easily leads to
>   just whitelisting the affected domains, hoping that this helps,
>   defeating the purpose of the filter in the first place. Filters will
>   also fail to do their job if an adversary simply registers a new
>   domain or creates a new URL path. Worse still, the unique filter sets
>   that each user creates or installs will provide a wealth of
>   fingerprinting targets.
>
> As a general matter, we are also generally opposed to shipping an
>   always-on Ad blocker with Tor Browser. We feel that this would damage
>   our credibility in terms of demonstrating that we are providing
>   privacy through a sound design alone, as well as damage the acceptance
>   of Tor users by sites that support themselves through advertising
>   revenue.
>
> Users are free to install these addons if they wish, but doing so is
>   not recommended, as it will alter the browser request fingerprint.